# Java generating query from resultSet and executing the new query

Tags: java, resultset

I am trying to use some query result to generate another query and execute the new query but that does not seem to work. The second query is not being executed. Can someone please tell me why? This is that part of the code.

```
Statment stmt = connnection.createStatement();
Statment stmt2 = connnection.createStatement();
ResultSet r =  stmt.executeQuery("Select * from employees");
while (r.next()) {
            String Str = "Select name from employees where employeeId = " + (r.getInt(3) + 1);
            System.out.println(str);
            query = stmt2.executeQuery(str);
            System.out.println(query.getString(1));}
```

The right query seems to be generated, but just won't execute. Is there a reason why this is so. BTW "query" is declared as resultset.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this is just simple sample code, but you could simply rewrite this N+1 query to be a single query to get all the data you want.

Comment: What is the need to select all employee rows and then fire off a query for each to get the name of employeeid = this.id + 1? You could rewrite this to be a single query, something like `select e2.name from employee e1 inner join employee e2 on e2.employeeid = e1.employeeid + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only have one statement executing at one moment in time against one database connection -- so you can either open another database connection and execute the second statement in the 2nd connection, or iterate through the resultset from first statement and store the employees database id's (e.g. in an array/collection) then close that statement and run the second one, this time retrieving the id's from the array/collection you saved them in.

Comment: Thank you. What if the Resultset r is passed as a parameter to the current class? That is, the statement is executed in a previous class and in this class, I am only using the results from that query to generate another query and run it? I established a connection in both classes but that still does not work. Please help

Comment: That is not a good design to pass a resultset around! But assuming someone has implemented the classes that way and you have no control over it, I would suggest you go with a solution which maybe builds a set of id's like `(id1, id2, id3...)` by iterating through the data in the resultset -- then this string can be used in another query like `select * from employees where id in <yourstring>`

Comment: why can't I pass a resultset as a param? WIll try that. Thanks

Comment: because the function you pass it to i'm assuming needs the **data** not the database resultset. The function receing the resultset can do all sorts with the resultset (including deleting data!). Also you are leaving the database connection open until the function returns so if the function is badly implemented one and takes forever you are blocking a database connection (and all the associated resources) for no other reasons but just to retrieve data from it in a lazy manner.

Comment: So, I tried that. I loop through my ids to generate my query and then execute it, but it give me the following error: java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set. I called the query.next() before the getting the value, but it still gives me this error :(

Comment: that error suggests that the query you built returned no results. if `next()` returns false then there is no data returned. What does the sql you are running look like?

Comment: @jpo let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1327/discussion-between-liv-and-jpo)