# How to perform a select query on the ResultSet of another select query in java

Tags: java, sql, db2

This is the code where I'm trying to execute a second query on the `resultSet` of my first lengthy query. I need to upload this 
  data somewhere.

Is it the right thing to do?

Or is there a better approach apart from querying the database again?

```
 public String createQuery() throws SQLException {
     StringBuilder Query = new StringBuilder();
     try {
        Query.append(" SELECT ...... ")
       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Query.toString();
}
 private void openPreparedStatements() throws SQLException {
    myQuery = createQuery();      
    try {
        QueryStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
public ResultSet selectData(String timestamp) throws SQLException {
    openConnection();
    ResultSet result = null;
    ResultSet rs_new=null;
    try {
        result = QueryStatement.executeQuery();
        while (result.next()) {
           String query = "SELECT * FROM " + result + " WHERE " + "ID" + " =" + "ABC";
            rs_new =QueryStatementNew.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.print(rs_new);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Exception", e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You need to nest this code with your resultset code.

Comment: I read that this approach is not suitable at all, Do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: Please share detailed code snippets to have clear idea of your implementation.

Comment: updated the full code

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running two separate queries (when you don't need the intermediate one) you can combine them.

For example you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  -- first query here
) x
WHERE ID = 'ABC'
```

Comment: I need two different resultSet as I need do send the first one to FTP and second one to elastic

Comment: Then the answer is no. You are asking to **materialize** a result set, and then use it to run a second query. DB2 (and most databases) don't work that way If you run the composite query (like this one) for efficiency purposes the engine won't materialize the first query, but will **pipeline** it. You'll need to run both queries separately.

Comment: Is there any reason for why we can't do that? Any documentations? Pls let me know

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use two statement objects within one database connection. So you can either open another database connection and execute the second statement in the 2nd connection, or iterate through the resultset from first statement and store the value you need (e.g. in an array/collection) then close that statement and run the second one, this time retrieving the value from the array/collection you saved them in. Refer to [Java generating query from resultSet and executing the new query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653190/java-generating-query-from-resultset-and-executing-the-new-query)

Answer (score 0):

Make Db2 keep your intermediate result set in a Global Temporary Table, if you have an ability to use it, and you application uses the same database connection session.

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TMP_RES AS 
(
SELECT ID, ... -- Your first lengthy query text goes here
) WITH DATA WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;
```

You may send the result of subsequent `SELECT ... FROM SESSION.TMP_RES` to FTP, and the result of `SELECT * FROM SESSION.TMP_RES WHERE ID = 'ABC'` to elastic.